# Search the calendar for appointments in a time period

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Excel macro that filters calendar appointments by dates. I have used the code given by Microsoft Docs, but it does not work.
I want to iterate the default calendar to find appoints that will occur between today and 30 days from today.

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub P1()
    Dim oOutlook              As Object
    Dim oNS                   As Object
    Dim oAppointments         As Object
    Dim oFilterAppointments   As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem      As Object
    Dim bOutlookOpened        As Boolean
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9
    
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim dateEnd As String
        
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bOutlookOpened = False    'Outlook was not already running, we had to start it
    Else
        bOutlookOpened = True    'Outlook was already running
    End If
 
    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
    oAppointments.Sort [Start]

    oAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
    
    dateEnd = DateAdd("d", 30, Date)
   
    sFilter = "[Start] >= '" & Date & " 'AND [Start] <= '" & dateEnd & "'"

    Debug.Print sFilter


    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sFilter)

    
    'Iterate through each appt in our calendar
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilterAppointments
        Debug.Print oAppointmentItem.Start

    Next


End Sub
```

The filter restriction for today is `[Start] >= '03/02/2021 'AND [Start] <= '14/05/2021`
but the first appointment that finds is from 2019. The last appointment that it returns fits the filter `(13/05/2021)`.
I have tried different variations of the filter but it always returns the same appointments of 2019.

Comment: Edit the question to put in code that runs. [mcve].

Comment: Make sure the date values are formatted correctly - use US format with mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: The format of oAppointmentItem.Start is dd/mm/yyyy, but just to check I have tried using the USA format, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Would you confirm this code is in Outlook.

Comment: This code is on Excel

Comment: This code does not run. Edit the question to put in code that possible responders can run without any changes. [mcve]. Please put `Option Explict`at the top.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I have edited the code and it's now runable.

Comment: You fell into a trap that likely has caused more than a few people to quit VBA. Consider mandatory a `On Error GoTo 0` closely following `On Error Resume Next`. (This is a better way to get Outlook as the error bypass is on one line only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059917/how-to-verify-outlook-session-is-open-or-not-using-vba/22060066#22060066.) Once you have an `On Error GoTo 0` step through your code and compare the lines with errors to my code.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, I did what you said and corrected the errors, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a small date discrepancy so there may be more to your scenario.

`.Sort` before `.Restrict`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub P1()
    
    Dim oAppointments         As Items
    Dim oFilterAppointments   As Items
    Dim oAppointmentItem      As AppointmentItem
    
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim dateEnd As Date
    
    Set oAppointments = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
    
    ' .Sort before .Restrict
    oAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
    oAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
    dateEnd = DateAdd("d", 30, Date)
    sFilter = "[Start] >= '" & Date & " 'AND [Start] <= '" & dateEnd & "'"
    Debug.Print sFilter

    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Restrict(sFilter)
   
    'Iterate through filtered appointments
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilterAppointments
        Debug.Print oAppointmentItem.Start
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed it but it still shows appointments from 2019, thanks for replying