# Excel VBA to get all meetings from Outlook including recurrences

Tags: vba, outlook, export-to-excel

this is my first time posting to StackOverflow so please bare with me if I'm doing something wrong.

I am using the following macro to get a list of meetings older than 7 days but I can't figure out how to get it to show recurring meetings. Can you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
  Option Explicit

Sub ListAppointments()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim NextRow As Long

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)
Worksheets("GetMeetings").Activate

Range("A1:e1").Value = Array("Organizer", "Subject", "Start", "End")

NextRow = 2
   
   For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
    If (olApt.Start >= Now - 7) Then
    

    Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Organizer
    Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = olApt.Subject
    Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.Start
    Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.End
    'Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Else
    End If
Next olApt

    'AutoFit
    Worksheets("GetMeetings").Columns.AutoFit

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search the calendar for appointments in a time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034331/search-the-calendar-for-appointments-in-a-time-period)

Comment: You can check the AppointmentItem's IsRecurring property, then RecurrenceState.

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.getoccurrence

Answer (score 0):

You can expand recurrences if you use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` and set the `Items.IncludeRecurrences` to true. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences for an example and more details.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will look into it and will post the code snippet once it works as expected.